# An initial query still showing on React Query Dev Tools

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-query

**Hello There!**
Here you can see a minimal reproducible example of the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-breeze-gdlsbu?file=/src/Discover.js

I've been trying to solve this issue:

If you search for Rick and Morty characters on this app, you will get a list with search results, then you can click on an individual character to get more information, but *when you click on back*, you are supposed to see the search results that you had before.

Instead of that, there is nothing and react-query seems to be caching a null search results

This is how I am trying to wire up the HTTP requests with react query

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState();

  const getByCharacterName = (apiEndPoint) => {
    return fetch(apiEndPoint).then(async (response) => {
      const data = await response.json();
      return response.ok ? data : Promise.reject(data);
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchInput(event.target.elements.search.value);
  };

  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess } = useQuery(
    [searchInput],
    () =>
      getByCharacterName(
        `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${searchInput}`
      ),
    {
      enabled: Boolean(searchInput)
    }
  );
```

Comment: Is your question about the `react-query` dev tools? Or something with app routing/navigation? Can you narrow the focus of your question(s) and provide a [mcve] and clearer reproduction steps so we've better context for what the code is doing?

Comment: Hello @DrewReese, thanks for the tips, I just updated the question, I would really be forever thankful for any help I can get on this issue. Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

searchInput is a param not a query key. Your query key should be a string and then you can add your params in the array. Also you don't need to reject, react-query handles rejections, retries, and caching automatically. You only need to return your json.

```
let getData = async () => await (await fetch('....')).json()
```

isError will tell you if there is something wrong. If you want more control over your query you can pass options, or even disable it and run it manually with refetch().

You can pass options like this:

```
useQuery('query-key', () => getData(), {
   onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
     //your logic here. This function can be async as well.
     //If you want access to the response, remove the nested await from
     //the request and make this function async. Then you can get the
     // status code with data.statusCode
     // and the json with await data.json()
   },
   onError: (error, variables, context) => {
     //handle errors here
   }
})
```